# Slow GUI update of a wx (Python) widget?

Tags: python, wxpython

Consider this example (tried on python2.7, Ubuntu 11.04):

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.knobctrl as KC

# started from: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.knobctrl.html

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "KnobCtrl Demo")

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

    self.knob1 = KC.KnobCtrl(self, -1, size=(100, 100))
    self.knob1.SetTags(range(0, 151, 10))
    self.knob1.SetAngularRange(-45, 225)
    self.knob1.SetValue(45)

    # explicit sizes here - cannot figure out the expands ATM
    self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))
    self.slider_1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, -12, 12, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_INVERSE, size=(150, -1))
    self.text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))

    main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    main_sizer.Add(self.knob1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.slider_1, 0, wx.EXPAND , 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)

    self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
    main_sizer.Layout()
    self.knob1.Bind(KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED, self.OnAngleChanged)
    self.slider_1.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)

  def OnAngleChanged(self, e):
    theknob = e.EventObject
    x = theknob._mousePosition.x
    y = theknob._mousePosition.y
    ang = theknob.GetAngleFromCoord(x, y)
    self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue("%.2f" % (ang))
    self.text_ctrl_1.Refresh() # no dice
  def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
    obj = e.GetEventObject()
    val = obj.GetValue()
    self.text_ctrl_2.SetValue(str(val))

# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

It results with something like this:

[image: test.png]

The thing is: if you move the slider very fast, you will notice the bottommost text box updates also rather fast; but if you move the rotary knob very fast, it seems its text box (below it) changes with much reduced frequency ?!

Why is this; and would it be possible to get the response speed of the rotary knob's text box to be as fast as slider's one?

Comment: First of all you have created a panel and assigned the sizer to it, but the widgets the sizer is managing have the frame as the parent.  I needed to fix that before I could interact with the widgets on OSX, so it may be part of your main problem too.  After that change on OSX (at least) the text widget is being updated at the speed I would expect while the knob is being twisted.  What version of wxPython are you using?

Comment: Hi @RobinDunn, thanks for the comment! `print(wx.VERSION_STRING)` says `2.8.11.0`; as far as the panel/sizer thing goes, I mostly copied it from the original link (in the code), I'm not really profficient in `wx` otherwise. Should the widgets have the panel as the parent? I'll try to capture a video of the behavior I get and post it somewhere... Cheers!

Comment: @RobinDunn - managed to capture a short video, but below in the answer is a better one - I added printouts from the event handler, and (if I use `EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED` and `e.Skip()`), then it's visible that the printouts are at decent speed - but the text box update isn't; as if there's a bunch of events being added, hogging the GUI event queue... Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I got something working, but I'm not 100% sure, so a more erudite answer would be appreciated. First, note that:

- The `wx.Slider` widget is (I think) implemented in C; so the only time Python "knows" anything about its execution is when the widget broadcasts an event
- The `wx.lib.agw.knobctrl.KnobCtrl` is implemented in Python; thus the Python interpreter "knows" (as it has to run it) each line of code of the widget's execution.

So, what I did, is I tried to trace the execution, with:

```bash
python -m trace --trace --timing test.py > test.pylog
```

What I could notice is that: `OnSliderScroll` appeared in the log apparently without being triggered by a mouse event, while multiple `OnMouseEvents` would appear from knobctrl.py (the mouseovers), and only some would trigger `SetTrackPosition()` which eventually calls `OnAngleChanged()`. But even more importantly, there was a *ton* of `_gdi_.DC_DrawLine` in the log! Then, looking at the `knobctrl.py` source, I realised that the gradient is actually painted in a Python `for` loop, line-by-line:

```python
def DrawDiagonalGradient(self, dc, size):
...
    for ii in xrange(0, maxsize, 2):
        currCol = (r1 + rf, g1 + gf, b1 + bf)                
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(currCol, 2))
        dc.DrawLine(0, ii+2, ii+2, 0)
...
```

... so I thought, this must be hogging the time! So, what is done in the code below, is that a subclass is derived from `KnobCtrl`, where `DrawDiagonalGradient()` so it uses a plain fill instead of a gradient, which works much faster.

So, the code below compares the original and the derived variant, using the same event handler and the same textfield; you can check out the video at https://vid.me/kM8V, which looks something like this:

[image: test2.png]

You'll notice the textctrl barely changes when the original knob is turned (even if, notably, the printouts are emitted with the expected speed) ; but updates pretty decently when the derived knob with "plain" background is turned (nearly as fast as the slider). I think the "plain" goes even faster when there is no draw of any kind in the overloaded method, but then the previous positions of the knob dot are not erased. My guess is, the draws of the original knob's gradient take up so much time in the allocated drawing timeframe, that Python needs to drop other queued updates for that frame, here notably the update of the text control.

Note that the knob emits both `KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGING` (which will not refresh the draw unless `e.Skip()` is present in the handler), and `KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED`; however, as far as I can see, they always follow each other, so below *`CHANGED` is used for both.

Of course, if I've misunderstood the problem and the solution, I'd love to know...

```python
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.knobctrl as KC

# started from: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.knobctrl.html

class KnobCtrlPlain(KC.KnobCtrl):
  def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
               size=wx.DefaultSize,
               agwStyle=KC.KC_BUFFERED_DC):
    super(KnobCtrlPlain, self).__init__(parent, id, pos, size, agwStyle)
  def DrawDiagonalGradient(self, dc, size):
    col1 = self._startcolour
    r1, g1, b1 = int(col1.Red()), int(col1.Green()), int(col1.Blue())
    sizex, sizey = size
    # must have a filled draw here, to erase previous draws:
    dc.SetPen(wx.TRANSPARENT_PEN)
    dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(col1, wx.SOLID))
    #~ dc.DrawCircle(self.Width/2, self.Height/2, sizex)
    dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, sizex, sizey) # same effect as circle; prob. faster?


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "KnobCtrl DemoB")
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.knob1 = KC.KnobCtrl(self.panel, -1, size=(100, 100))
    self.knob1.SetTags(range(0, 151, 10))
    self.knob1.SetAngularRange(-45, 225)
    self.knob1.SetValue(45)
    self.knob2 = KnobCtrlPlain(self.panel, -1, size=(100, 100))
    self.knob2.SetTags(range(0, 151, 10))
    self.knob2.SetAngularRange(-45, 225)
    self.knob2.SetValue(45)
    self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))
    self.slider_1 = wx.Slider(self.panel, -1, 0, -12, 12, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_INVERSE, size=(150, -1))
    self.text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))
    main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    main_sizer.Add(self.knob1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.knob2, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.slider_1, 0, wx.EXPAND , 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)
    self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
    main_sizer.Layout()
    self.knob1.Bind(KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED, self.OnAngleChanged)
    self.knob2.Bind(KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED, self.OnAngleChanged)
    self.slider_1.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)
  def OnAngleChanged(self, e):
    theknob = e.EventObject
    x = theknob._mousePosition.x
    y = theknob._mousePosition.y
    ang = theknob.GetAngleFromCoord(x, y)
    strval = str("%.2f" % (ang))
    print("ac: " + strval)
    self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue(strval)
  def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
    obj = e.GetEventObject()
    val = obj.GetValue()
    strval = str(val)
    print("ss: " + strval)
    self.text_ctrl_2.SetValue(strval)

# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual
app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```