# Print out / list pending events queue from an event handler in wx python?

Tags: python, wxpython

In the code below ([Slow GUI update of a wx (Python) widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684059/slow-gui-update-of-a-wx-python-widget)), how could I print out a list of which events are queued at that moment, let's say from the `OnAngleChanged` handler?

I've seen that there exists e.g. [wx.PyApp.ProcessPendingEvents()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PyApp-class.html#ProcessPendingEvents), so there must be a list of pending events of sorts; but `ProcessPendingEvents()` seems to be an interface to a C function (as per `wx/_core.py`), and I cannot really find what that list is, or how to have it printed from Python.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.knobctrl as KC

# started from: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.knobctrl.html

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "KnobCtrl Demo")

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

    self.knob1 = KC.KnobCtrl(self, -1, size=(100, 100))
    self.knob1.SetTags(range(0, 151, 10))
    self.knob1.SetAngularRange(-45, 225)
    self.knob1.SetValue(45)

    # explicit sizes here - cannot figure out the expands ATM
    self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))
    self.slider_1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, -12, 12, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL|wx.SL_AUTOTICKS|wx.SL_INVERSE, size=(150, -1))
    self.text_ctrl_2 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "0", size=(50, -1))

    main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    main_sizer.Add(self.knob1, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.slider_1, 0, wx.EXPAND , 20)
    main_sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl_2, 0, wx.EXPAND, 20)

    self.panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)
    main_sizer.Layout()
    self.knob1.Bind(KC.EVT_KC_ANGLE_CHANGED, self.OnAngleChanged)
    self.slider_1.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnSliderScroll)

  def OnAngleChanged(self, e):
    theknob = e.EventObject
    x = theknob._mousePosition.x
    y = theknob._mousePosition.y
    ang = theknob.GetAngleFromCoord(x, y)
    self.text_ctrl_1.SetValue("%.2f" % (ang))
    self.text_ctrl_1.Refresh() # no dice
  def OnSliderScroll(self, e):
    obj = e.GetEventObject()
    val = obj.GetValue()
    self.text_ctrl_2.SetValue(str(val))

# our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```